# PHP foreach loop on dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, global-variables

I have to execute function "one" and function "two" at different places in my code.
I set the function one variables in a dynamic array in order to use them in the function 2 by setting the array as a global variable.

Then, when I call the function two by using the 1st value of the array, I can get the variable of each key.

This works well and it is ok when I have a limited number of arrays...

Now, I'll have to call many function one and I would like to automatize the execution of the function two.
I thought to use a foreach loop for this.
Unless, I am not familiar with foreach structure, I can not find the way to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Etienne

Here is my code :

```
function one($nom,$a,$b,$c)
{
    global $$nom;
    $$nom = array($a,$b,$c);
}

function two($nom)
{
    global $$nom;
    echo ${$nom}[0].'</br>'.${$nom}[2].'</br>';
}

one("D1",10,20,30);
one("D2",100,200,300);

two("D1"); // works but i do not want to write it manually
two("D2"); // I want to use the foreach loop for that

  foreach(${$nom} as $value) {
       two($nom);
  }
```

Comment: Hands off from `global` !!

Comment: Ok, but how ? (I'm "just" a mechanical engineer)

Comment: How what? Don't use them! Code object oriented instead, use classes & objects... you don't want/need the evil globals ;) + get rid off the _variable variables_ `$$`

Comment: Ok, I found a tutorial to learn this and know I see what you are talking about. The tutorial is very long, and I have no time yet to follow it. So, until I will find the time, I will remove this part of my code and put manually the arguments in each function two. Thank for your help.
Cheers. Etienne